# Are there any libraries to create uml diagrams programmatically

Tags: graphics, uml

I want to create uml diagrams with table information from a database. Are there any libraries to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can either create a text-based representation of the UML model and use one of this [textual UML tools](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual) to render it graphically or, use the APIs that some UML tools provide to programmatically create the UML model from, e.g., a Java program. For the latter you may want to take a look at the Eclipse Modeling Projects in Eclipse and in particular the UML2 component

Answer (score 2):

UML is a big thing, but some time ago I did a similar task with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Actually, my code generated a *dot* file, which is the input format accepted by the graphviz utilities to draw things.

Comment: i only want to create simple class diagrams, with table name and it's columns/attributes.

Comment: Graphviz can be tested in no time, just to see if it fits :) The problem with automatic generation is usually with usefulness of the resulting diagram. If you don't have a complex hierarchy and most of your objects are siblings (lying on the same level) the final draw will not be very interesting

Answer (score 0):

Almost any good diagramming library should be able to create UML diagrams programmatically. Depending on what type of UML diagram you need (class diagram, sequence diagram, collaboration, etc. ) the generic diagramming libraries will definitely work. See here for example:

[yFiles Gallery of Diagrams](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_gallery.html)

If you are looking for tools that will automatically do this for you, take a look at

[DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/)